# Unexpected results of `texdef` with command defined in "book.cls"

Tags: tex-core

When asking `texdef` for command defined in `book.cls` we get "undefined" as response.

```latex
$ texdef -t latex -s \chapter

\chapter:
undefined
```

But if the command is defined in `article.cls` we get a valid result:

```latex
$ texdef -t latex -s \section
% article.cls, line 302:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

How can I query commands defined in `book.cls`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The default class used when the class is not explicitly mentioned is `article`, and since that class doesn't define `\chapter` it reports that correctly.

To check for commands inside another class you need to explicitly state the class using the `-class` or `-c` option.

```
texdef -t latex -c book -s \chapter

% book.cls, line 350:
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

If you don't know the package that defines a particular command, and you have an up-to-date TeXLive or MikTeX, you can try the `texfindpkg` utility.  It can find (and install) package dependencies as well as find packages given a command name.  Here's an example:

```
$ texfindpkg query '\Soprano'

[tfp] you are using texlive
[tfp] found package file recorder-fingering.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for recorder-fingering.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for tikz.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for pgf.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for pgfrcs.sty
[tfp] no dependency info for everyshi.sty
[tfp] no dependency info for tikzlibrarycalc.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for graphicx.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for keyval.sty
[tfp] finding dependencies for trig.sty
[tfp] please install texlive package recorder-fingering pgf pgf pgf graphics graphics graphics
```

Which correctly finds that the `\Soprano` command is defined by the `recorder-fingering` package.

If you search for a command that multiple packages defines it will give you all the relevant packages and dependencies:

```
$ texfindpkg query '\Tree'
[tfp] you are using texlive
[tfp] ================================================
[tfp] found package file logicpuzzle.sty with command \Tree
[tfp] building dependency tree for logicpuzzle.sty:
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] logicpuzzle.sty (from logicpuzzle)
[tfp] |- xkeyval.sty (from xkeyval)
[tfp] |- ifthen.sty (from latex)
[tfp] |- ragged2e.sty (from ragged2e)
[tfp]    |- footmisc.sty (from footmisc)
[tfp] |- marginnote.sty (from marginnote)
[tfp] |- tikz.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]    |- pgf.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]       |- pgfrcs.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]          |- everyshi.sty (from everyshi)
[tfp] |- tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex (from pgf)
[tfp] |- tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex (from pgf)
[tfp]    |- tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex (from pgf)
[tfp] |- tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex (from pgf)
[tfp] |- tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex (from pgf)
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] texlive packages needed: logicpuzzle xkeyval latex ragged2e footmisc marginnote pgf everyshi
[tfp] these packages are already installed
[tfp] ================================================
[tfp] found package file qtree.sty with command \Tree
[tfp] building dependency tree for qtree.sty:
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] qtree.sty (from qtree)
[tfp] |- pict2e.sty (from pict2e)
[tfp]    |- trig.sty (from graphics)
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] texlive packages needed: qtree pict2e graphics
[tfp] these packages are already installed
[tfp] ================================================
[tfp] found package file tikz-qtree.sty with command \Tree
[tfp] building dependency tree for tikz-qtree.sty:
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] tikz-qtree.sty (from tikz-qtree)
[tfp] |- tikz.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]    |- pgf.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]       |- pgfrcs.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]          |- everyshi.sty (from everyshi)
[tfp] |- pgftree.sty (from tikz-qtree)
[tfp]    |- pgffor.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]       |- pgfmath.sty (from pgf)
[tfp]    |- pgfsubpic.sty (from tikz-qtree)
[tfp] ------------------------
[tfp] texlive packages needed: tikz-qtree pgf everyshi
[tfp] these packages are already installed
[tfp] ================================================
[tfp] texlive packages not yet installed in total:
```

This means, however, if you look for something that lots of packages or classes define (like your original example `\chapter` it will in practical terms return *a lot* of things. The information will be there, however, but it will be quite a bit of searching to find it. For example:

```
$ texfindpkg query '\chapter'
```

returns 1039 lines of output.

A more comprehensive search can be done by using `grep`:

```
$ grep -r '\Tree' /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex
```

But this will also require some digging to find packages that are actually defining the specific command.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. But what when we don't know the class where the command is defined in? When we don't know the package texdef will find the package.

Comment: @wolfrevo There's not really a good solution to that problem. And I'm pretty sure `texdef` does not find packages for you.

Comment: @wolfrevo If you give it a list of packages to check, then yes, it will find it, but without a list it will not.

Comment: Just for the record, a newer `texfindpkg` (version 2023E or later) produces much better results. Perhaps the answer could be updated

Comment: @mbert Thanks for the reminder. I've updated the answer accordingly. Based on the original answer I raised the issue on the package repository and the author very quickly updated the tool.